# Android app is running with debugger on emulator but not showing up in app list

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed an app in AndroidStudio (2.3 Beta 4) on osx and I can deploy it to the emulator and it will run right away.
But I can not find the app with its icon even when I search for it. 
The only place where I find is in Settings->Apps

One thing to note is that the MainActivity inherits from a MasterActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends MasterActivity implements ...

 public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
    <application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--<activity android:name=".SelectAndCompressActivity">-->
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />-->

            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />-->
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->

            <!--<data android:mimeType="image/*" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    <!--</activity>-->
</application>
```

How do I make the app appear like all other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is happening because of writing a lot inside single intent filter. Could you try doing following manipulation in your manifest code:
         `

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>


        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`
```

Comment: Saarang! Highly appreciated your help. You are right. Now the app does appear. Can you explain why it is not possible to put everything into one filter?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason. But I found this on Google's Android API. Refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving). and check Example filters.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Generally this should work.**
   Well, if the layout is coming from the `MasterActivity` then mention it in the    manifest as well, like:

   `<activity android:name=".MasterActivity"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
           />`
2. Also, check if there is any value for:
   `android:label="@string/app_name"` in the string file of res folder.
3. If these steps don't solve the issue then try to delete the application from the device and re-install it from the android studio.

Comment: Thank you Saarang, but I checked already all the mentioned steps. The layout is coming from the MainActivity and not Master

Comment: I tried to create a similar application and it worked fine. If the code is not very big then could you try to create the android studio project again and check if it works?

Comment: I wiped the app from the workspace and cloned it again from a git repo without success. I also deleted the app on the device
./adb uninstall appname Still I don't see the app

Comment: Could you send me the link of the application that you are trying clone from GIT repo. Or, may be you can try to create your own application by copying the code from the cloned application.